# JS input text to url + base64 encode

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS so i'm gonna try to explain the prob.
I'm looking for a JS to perform some tasks like: input text form to include certain "text" in a base64 decoded string and then encode that string. Add that encoded result to an url and open that url on submit.

the base64 decode string is something like:

```
{
   "componentDef":"forceSearch:search",
   "attributes":{
      "term":"SEARCH STRING 2",
      "scopeMap":{
         "type":"TOP_RESULTS"
      },
      "context":{
         "disableSpellCorrection":false,
         "SEARCH_ACTIVITY":{
            "term":"SEARCH STRING 2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

the input text form should replace both SEARCH STRING 2 with the text submited something like:

```
{
   "componentDef":"forceSearch:search",
   "attributes":{
      "term":"MYSUBMITEXT",
      "scopeMap":{
         "type":"TOP_RESULTS"
      },
      "context":{
         "disableSpellCorrection":false,
         "SEARCH_ACTIVITY":{
            "term":"MYSUBMITEXT"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

after that the result should be base64 encoded:

```
btoa({
   "componentDef":"forceSearch:search",
   "attributes":{
      "term":"MYSUBMITEXT",
      "scopeMap":{
         "type":"TOP_RESULTS"
      },
      "context":{
         "disableSpellCorrection":false,
         "SEARCH_ACTIVITY":{
            "term":"MYSUBMITEXT"
         }
      }
```

and after encoded the result should be added to url

`onClick="javascript: window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/print/' + encoded result)"`

My currently main issue in on the replacing the 2 search strings. im unable to replace it because its coded?!

UPDATE:

i currently have this code but the encode is always the same so im not user the text value is being puted:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function goToPage() {
var searchQuery = document.getElementById('text').value;
var stringToEncode = '{"componentDef":"forceSearch:search","attributes":{"term":"'+ searchQuery + '","scopeMap":{"type":"TOP_RESULTS"},"context":{"disableSpellCorrection":false,"SEARCH_ACTIVITY":{"term":"'+ searchQuery + '"}}}}';
var encodedString = btoa(stringToEncode);
document.write("http://www.mywebsite.com/print/" + encodedString);
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="goToPage();" />
</html>
```

Comment: Can you format your question properly so its easy to read. Put the codes in the tags or mark up they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the string to a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse`

```
var myString = '{"componentDef":"forceSearch:search","attributes":{"term":"SEARCH STRING 2","scopeMap":{"type":"TOP_RESULTS"},"context":{"disableSpellCorrection":false,"SEARCH_ACTIVITY":{"term":"SEARCH STRING 2"}}}}';

var myObject = JSON.parse(myString);
```

2. Access the property in the object and replace it with the desired value

```
myObject.attributes.term = 'New value';
myObject.attributes.context.term = 'New value';
```

3. Convert the object back to a string and encode it using base64

```
var newString = JSON.stringify(myObject);
var encodedString = btoa(newString);
```

Click handler

```html
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/print/' + encodedString)">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Updated post with the currently code im using. Though im not sure the text value is being inserted since the encoded is always the same no matter what value i put